# My USB disk is running very slow

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, rufus

I was writing the Windows ISO file to my USB drive with Rufus but then I had to cancel the process. After canceling the process, the speed of my USB disk slowed down a lot. I tried every way I found on the internet but nothing worked. What should I do?

---

I formatted my USB disk as NTFS and gave 64 KB allocation to disk. Then I tried to transfer a file and the transfer rate remained at 355 kbps. Still too slow.
[image: usb disk file transfer speed]

Comment: Possibly format the USB drive and try again?

Comment: Like I said, I tried everything but it didn't work. I've formatted my USB disk quite a number of times. I plugged it in both my computer and my phone and formatted it with Android, but nothing changed. And the formatting speed is also very slow.

Comment: @Fatih - Can you tell us what exactly you have tried?  We don't want to waste your time suggesting the same solutions you have already eliminated.

Comment: I tried to speed it up by turning on the "Better Performance" option in Device Manager. Windows gave an error, I formatted my USB disk as NTFS, FAT32 or exFAT many times, but it did not solve my problem. I also tried other things at this link: https://www.easeus.com/computer-instruction/fix-slow-usb-transfer-speed.html

Comment: @Fatih - try to do a regular windows quick format as NTFS with >=64KB allocation size (even if you have less space on the stick it would perform a bit better when reading small files)

After format - try to copy a large file (i.e. >100MB) and check the average speed; 
check which version of USB your stick has and (evidently) which version of USB is the port you're putting it into; regardless of USB version you should have at least 10-20MB/s read and 5-10MB/s write with a regular stick

Comment: @Mache - Ok, I'll try this but formatting the USB disk takes quite a long time.

Comment: If it's a cheap USB drive it might be an inherent issue - once you've written enough data to it, it must now do a slower [erase cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Block_erasure) due to its physical limitations and the fact that all blocks have been written to once.

Comment: @Fatih - that's why I'm saying to do a QUICK format

Comment: @nanofarad - Before, my disk was quite fast, there was no such problem. This is what happened after I canceled the writing of the ISO file.

Comment: @Mache - I know and I do quick formatting. I started the formatting process after you sent the message, but it's still 0%

Comment: @Fatih Yes, before you wrote the ISO to the disk, it had many free blocks. After writing the ISO file, it could have very few and thus will be much slower, especially with writes (or reads that are delayed because the computer is waiting for the disk to finish a write)

Comment: @Mache - I tried the way you said: https://superuser.com/a/1692467/1648245

Comment: I solved the problem. I tested my USB flash drive with CrystalDiskMark and after the test my flash drive regained its former speed.

Comment: Please [do not post solutions in the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/355310). Your first answer is not an answer. Your second answer (currently deleted) seems to be your solution. Solutions should be answers. Undelete and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/355310).

Answer (score 0):

In creating the bootable USB, *Rufus* likely created a second partition: one for boot, one for the OS. Simply formatting the USB device will not change that issue.

Use a disk management tool, such as Windows *Disk Management* or free third-party tool [*Disk Genius*](https://www.diskgenius.com/) to:

1. Delete all partitions.
2. Apply changes (in *Disk Genius*, click the *Save All* buttone0.
3. Now, create a single partition on the USB flash drive as FAT32 (in *Disk Genius*, click Quick Partition*, and *Save All* again).

**N.B.** Be **very** careful to make changes only to the USB flash drive, **Do Not** mess with the machines HDD or SSD!

Hopefully, the full USB flash drive will be available for storage at normal speed.

[image: Mate USB in Disk Management]

[image: Mate USB in Disk Genius]

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my problem.

Comment: I solved the problem. I tested my USB flash drive with CrystalDiskMark and after the test my flash drive regained its former speed.

Comment: @Fatih please add your solution as answer, not as comment, and mark it as correct answer.  Thank you.

Comment: THIS answer COULD only possibly fix "my USB drive got smaller".  MiniTool Partition Wizard Free 9.1 (2015) lets me create a partition on a USB drive that is smaller than the whole drive (which Windows 7 Disk Manager won't do) and even lets me start it in the middle (which shouldn't matter because flash blocks are remapped), but when I create a second partition, it first warns me "The new partition cannot be used in Windows. Because Windows could only recognize the first partition on a removable disk. Do you want to continue?"